# In Ada, what does it mean when you assign Object.All?

Tags: ada

Consider the following assignment:

```
procedure Assign(Original : myAccessType) is    
Other : myAccessType;

begin    
   Other.all := Original.all;
   Other.IntegerValue := Original.IntegerValue;  
end
```

I'm not really sure what the first assignment is doing.  What is the significance of the `.All` in the assignment? And, is the second assignment of the integer value still needed?

Comment: deep copy not shallow copy. Therefore the second assignment is redundant. Any textbook on Ada should have answered this.

Comment: I did some searching, but was unsuccessful in reaching an answer that made sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first assignment is going to raise `Constraint_Error`, because in Ada access values are initialized to `null`.

Assuming you wrote instead

```
Other : myAccessType := new myType;
```

then

```
Other.all := Original.all;
```

would mean (unless there’s some use of `Ada.Finalization` in there, [ARM 7.6](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-7-6.html)) that the bits pointed to by `Original` would be copied into the bits pointed to by `Other`.

Thus there’s be no need to do the second assignment.

I’m not an expert C programmer, but I think your code is equivalent to

```
typedef struct myType {
  int IntegerValue;
} *myAccessType;

void assign(myAccessType original)
{
  myAccessType other;     // uninitialized
  *other = *original;
  other->IntegerValue = original->IntegerValue;
}
```

Comment: So it's actually creating a copy, and not just a reference (aka a "deep copy" in C terminology)

Comment: Yes, but only to one level; if `myType` above contained a pointer-to-something, that pointer would be copied, and the two copies would point to the same memory.

Comment: I think that's a fair trade-off. In my particular case, I don't believe that would present an issue.

Answer (score 2):

`.all` is explicit dereferencing of an access type.

Comment: It actually does answer the question.

Comment: As the original asker, I respectfully disagree. Answers on Stack Overflow should be expounded upon until a clear answer is provided, along with supporting background info. If the asker (me) is confused by what is happening, an answer like Simon's is much more helpful to future readers than this. This answer addresses neither of my questions, particularly the second which deals with the practical usage.